# How to organize objects in an array using various property values of that object with the ES6 sort method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have an Array like this

```
let arr = [
    {label: "Bob Bobson", value: 17345, group: "Applicants"}
    {label: "Frank Frankson", value: 17347, group: "Applicants"}
    {label: "Bill Billson", value: 17348, group: "Applicants"}
    {label: "John Johnson", value: 1, group: "Caregivers"}
    {label: "Aaron Aaronson", value: 15, group: "Caregivers"}
    {label: "Jacob Jacobson", value: 172, group: "Clients"}
    {label: "Eric Ericsson", value: 1441, group: "Clients"}
    {label: "Doc Docson", value: 1147, group: "Doctors"}
]
```

I want to sort it using two of the property values in the object, the label property and the group property. I'm currently not getting any results however. I want to sort by group first and then label.

Here is what I am trying below.

```
arr.sort((a, b) => { a.label.toUpperCase() > b.label.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : -1 });
```

Using this I get the same results back, the label property doesn't get sorted.

Comment: FYI, `Array#sort` has existed for a long time. It's not new to ES6.

Answer (score -1):

Your sort function isn't returning anything. Arrow functions can do an implicit return statement, but only if you have no curly brackets. So either remove the curly brackets, or add a return statement. Also, you have an extra closing parentheses after `b.label.toUpperCase()`

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.label.toUpperCase() > b.label.toUpperCase() ? 1 : -1 );

arr.sort((a, b) => { 
    return a.label.toUpperCase() > b.label.toUpperCase() ? 1 : -1 
});
```

Comment: Ok i see this ends up sorting the label property and scrambles the group property.

Comment: Yes, i was showing you why no sorting was happening. If you want to modify the sorting condition further, feel free to.

Comment: to continue sorting it do I just chain the command ?

Comment: The function that you pass into .sort determines how it's sorted. If you want it to be sorted by group, then instead of comparing labels, compare groups. If you want it to be sorted by both, then compare both.

Comment: Ok got it , thanks. Yeah I wasn't returning a value which caused it to error up.